# How can I align vertically a bar progress inside a td?

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, html-table

Hey I have this table :

[image]

This is part of the code:

```
$('#grid_proyecto_id').append(
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td id = "td_project_id" class="text-center">'+value.nombrePro+'</td>'+
                        '<td id = "td_project_id" class="text-center">'+value.numTareasPro+'</td>'+
                        '<td id = "td_project_id" class="text-center">'+value.numUsuariosPro+'</td>'+
                        '<td id = "td_project_id" class="text-center">'+value.numTerminadasPro+'</td>'+
                        '<td id = "td_project_id" class="text-center">'+value.numNoTerminadasPro+'</td>'+
                        '<td id = "td_bar_id" class="text-center"><div  class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '+value.numPorcentajePro+'%;">'+value.numPorcentajePro+' %</div></div></td>'+                    
                    '</tr>'
               );
```

In CSS I use:

```
#td_project_id{

vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And works with all the td , except with the last td:

```
'<td id = "td_bar_id" class="text-center"><div  class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '+value.numPorcentajePro+'%;">'+value.numPorcentajePro+' %</div></div></td>'+
```

I'm usign in CSS:

```
#td_bar_id{

vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but nothing..

How can I align vertically the last td?? (sorry my english)

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/ is a neat tool to fit your needs. I think there is some trouble with your progress outer div and block level elements.

Comment: Are all of the rows the same height? maybe just do it with changing the "top" or "margin-top" values in the css. Even if they are all the same height, uniform length from the divider line seems like it would look better than things being in the middle vertically for each column.

Comment: @JesseDockett hi , I want avoid top.. or margin top, i want a type of class or something :(

Comment: I have a jsfiddle trying to reproduce your problem (http://jsfiddle.net/2v9u1bu7/), but it is not showing up in my jsfiddle. Could you provide some of the css to your progress bar?

Comment: @Jeanbf Couldn't you do something like "# grid_proyecto_id tr > td.text-center {margin-top: 20px}?" I'm not sure what you mean by want a class or something. May be a translation thing.

Comment: The issue may be due to a height value in one of the CSS rules that affect the `div` elements within the `td`.  If one of the `div`'s has a height, then that height will determine the height of the table row and the numbers will be vertically centered but the progress bar will be at the top of the div.  We need to see all the CSS in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MarcAudet I Work with boostrap bar , the css is for defect , I use the progress bar of this page : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment

Comment: I fix the problem for now with this : .progress{margin-top: 20px;}

Comment: `margin-bottom: 0px;` also worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Since Bootstrap adds a `margin-bottom: 20px;` to its progress bars `.progress` class, you just need to add this to your CSS to make them properly `vertically-align: middle;` inside table cells:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td > .progress {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```